# Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* not being recognized by Angular.js $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm developing a javascript app to control some smart TVs but angular pre lights OPTIONS requests before try the POST request (SOAP) I'm trying to send. The devices return a response with a proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` but angular refuses to send the POST request.

Of course, I can't change the configurations of the device's server to send another header angular "needs" and I need to send a `Cookie` and `Content-Type`.

How can I work around this?

---

UPDATE with a screenshot of request (bottom) and response (top) headers.

[image]

---

UPDATE with related angular code:

App is configured with:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}])
```

The request is:

```
var body = '<?xml version="1.0"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:X_SendIRCC xmlns:u="urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1"><IRCCCode>{command}</IRCCCode></u:X_SendIRCC></s:Body></s:Envelope>';
var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
    "SOAPACTION": "urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1#X_SendIRCC"
};
return $http({
    method:"POST",
    url: "http://{ip}/sony/IRCC".replace("{ip}", config.ip),
    data: body.replace("{command}", signal),
    headers: headers
});
```

Comment: You sure angular is pre-flighting the OPTIONS, and not your browser? AFAIK, it is the browser support & implementation that does this. Sounds like something else is going on. What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: no error messages, just a successful OPTIONS request but no POST request. I can curl successfully.

Comment: Sure you can `curl`, because curl doesn't have the same-origin access policy as a browser, so it doesn't need CORS enabled, or the pre-flight `OPTIONS`, or the server sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. I have had issues in the past with browsers not sending it out correctly. Can you post the `$http` code and the actual content (from Firebug or Developer Mode or whatever) of the `OPTIONS` request and response?

Comment: sure, I've updated the question with a screen shot.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. And the `$http` request?

Comment: Added. Notice that app is configured with `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials=true`

Comment: And do you have `$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true` set?

Comment: Tried with `$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true`, same issue.

Comment: I think your problem is with `withCredentials`. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: ok, just beware that withCredentials is necessary to send the auth cookies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is `withCredentials`. When you use `withCredentials`, the server *must* indicate that allows credentials. In a simple `GET` request that doesn't require preflighting, the browser is supposed to keep any such response from your app; in a preflighted request, it should not send the actual request.

Here is the best description at mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials

It says:

> but the browser will reject any response that does not have the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true header,
>   and not make the response available to the invoking web content

If you look at the preflight response, you see the headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "content-type,soapaction"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

But the required `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header is not there.

Comment: Well, I need to send the cookies and yet I can't send a patch to Sony so they can "fix" their devices with an `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header, so I'm probably stuck. I think I'll port the app to another language other than javascript and give up from running the app on the browser. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Ah, well. I can try to help understand the problem, but I definitely cannot change your smart TV device. I am kind of surprised that it supports CORS (as it shows with the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers, requires cookies, but doesn't support it!

Comment: That's probably because most SDKs only take into account native app development, so they simply forget to add the necessary header. Clients implemented in other languages don't care about these headers anyway.

Comment: Yeah, but they have some headers for CORS. Strange. Ah, well, that is what you get for an app from a TV maker. :-)

Comment: Well, the TV runs NginX server so probably somebody just forgot the header. But the biggest problem is the web browser not allowing you to do what you want because "security", when I can use any other HTTP client to do the same thing. At least browsers should give options to enable certain things for certain apps.

Comment: Yeah, you would need to delve into the whole history of cross-domain requests. I find the logic sometimes eludes me.

Answer (score 1):

The Options are only fetched if your browser does not know them,
so if you could beforehand load something from the server (regular not via soap) like including an invisible image, your browser should already know the options and not re request them.